# TypeScript conflict with flow when testing a react-native component

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a simple react-native boilerplate I am trying to test a test a simple react-native component written with typescript:

```
// Splash.tsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SContainer, STitle, SSubtitle, SPara } from './Splash.style';

export default class Splash extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SContainer>
        <STitle>Clean Slate</STitle>
        <SSubtitle>A react-native boilerplate</SSubtitle>
        <SPara>
          with TypeScript, React-Navigation, {'\n'}styled-components, Redux and
          Sagas
        </SPara>
      </SContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

`SContainer`, `STitle`, `SSubtitle` & `SPara` are `styled-components`

And I have this test:

```
// Splash.spec.tsx
import React from 'react';
import Splash from './Splash';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Splash onAppStart={() => {}} />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I have other jest tests of pure JS/TS functions (no JSX) and tests run and pass perfectly.
But when I run `jest -- -u` on Splash.spec.tsx I get this:

```sh
 FAIL  src/screens/Splash/Splash.spec.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:18:1 - error TS8002: 'import ... =' can only be used in a .ts file.

    18 import type {
       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:41:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    41 export type ViewStyleProp = ____ViewStyleProp_Internal;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:51:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    51 export type TextStyleProp = ____TextStyleProp_Internal;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:61:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    61 export type ImageStyleProp = ____ImageStyleProp_Internal;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:70:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    70 export type DangerouslyImpreciseStyleProp = ____DangerouslyImpreciseStyleProp_Internal;
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:88:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    88 export type TypeForStyleKey<
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:90:18 - error TS8011: 'type arguments' can only be used in a .ts file.

    90 > = $ElementType<____DangerouslyImpreciseStyle_Internal, key>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:107:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    107 export type ViewStyle = ____ViewStyle_Internal;
                    ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:124:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    124 export type TextStyle = ____TextStyle_Internal;
                    ~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:141:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    141 export type ImageStyle = ____ImageStyle_Internal;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:155:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    155 export type DangerouslyImpreciseStyle = ____DangerouslyImpreciseStyle_Internal;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:162:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    162 export type LayoutStyle = ____LayoutStyle_Internal;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:163:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    163 export type ShadowStyle = ____ShadowStyle_Internal;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:164:13 - error TS8008: 'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.

    164 export type TransformStyle = ____TransformStyle_Internal;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:171:21 - error TS8010: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

    171 const absoluteFill: LayoutStyle = {
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:253:32 - error TS8010: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

    253   absoluteFill: (absoluteFill: any), // TODO: This should be updated after we fix downstream Flow sites.
                                       ~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:275:11 - error TS8004: 'type parameter declarations' can only be used in a .ts file.

    275   compose<T: DangerouslyImpreciseStyleProp>(
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:276:13 - error TS8010: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

    276     style1: ?T,
                    ~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:277:13 - error TS8010: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

    277     style2: ?T,
                    ~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:278:6 - error TS8010: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

    278   ): ?T | $ReadOnlyArray<T> {
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:280:48 - error TS8011: 'type arguments' can only be used in a .ts file.

    280       return ([style1, style2]: $ReadOnlyArray<T>);
                                                       ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:337:15 - error TS8010: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

    337     property: string,
                      ~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:338:14 - error TS8010: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

    338     process: (nextProp: mixed) => mixed,
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:361:10 - error TS8004: 'type parameter declarations' can only be used in a .ts file.

    361   create<+S: ____Styles_Internal>(obj: S): $ObjMap<S, (Object) => any> {

    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:18:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected.

    18 import type {
                   ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:31:1 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

    31 } from 'StyleSheetTypes';
       ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:31:8 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

    31 } from 'StyleSheetTypes';
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:89:3 - error TS1139: Type parameter declaration expected.

    89   +key: $Keys<____DangerouslyImpreciseStyle_Internal>,
         ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:89:7 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

    89   +key: $Keys<____DangerouslyImpreciseStyle_Internal>,
             ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:89:54 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

    89   +key: $Keys<____DangerouslyImpreciseStyle_Internal>,
                                                            ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:90:1 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

    90 > = $ElementType<____DangerouslyImpreciseStyle_Internal, key>;
       ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:90:3 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

    90 > = $ElementType<____DangerouslyImpreciseStyle_Internal, key>;
         ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:90:62 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

    90 > = $ElementType<____DangerouslyImpreciseStyle_Internal, key>;
                                                                    ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:253:36 - error TS1005: '=>' expected.

    253   absoluteFill: (absoluteFill: any), // TODO: This should be updated after we fix downstream Flow sites.
                                           ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:275:12 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

    275   compose<T: DangerouslyImpreciseStyleProp>(
                   ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:280:31 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

    280       return ([style1, style2]: $ReadOnlyArray<T>);
                                      ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:280:50 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

    280       return ([style1, style2]: $ReadOnlyArray<T>);
                                                         ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:361:10 - error TS1139: Type parameter declaration expected.

    361   create<+S: ____Styles_Internal>(obj: S): $ObjMap<S, (Object) => any> {
                 ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:361:12 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

    361   create<+S: ____Styles_Internal>(obj: S): $ObjMap<S, (Object) => any> {
                   ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:361:38 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

    361   create<+S: ____Styles_Internal>(obj: S): $ObjMap<S, (Object) => any> {
                                             ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:361:41 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

    361   create<+S: ____Styles_Internal>(obj: S): $ObjMap<S, (Object) => any> {
                                                ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:361:42 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

    361   create<+S: ____Styles_Internal>(obj: S): $ObjMap<S, (Object) => any> {
                                                 ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:373:5 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

    373     return obj;
            ~~~~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:373:12 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

    373     return obj;
                   ~~~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:373:15 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

    373     return obj;
                      ~
    node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js:375:1 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

    375 };
        ~

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |    95.24 |    71.43 |      100 |    94.44 |                   |
 actions   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 reducers  |    92.31 |    71.43 |      100 |    92.31 |                   |
  index.ts |    92.31 |    71.43 |      100 |    92.31 |                34 |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Tests:       8 passed, 8 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.247s
Ran all test suites matching /src/i.

Active Filters: filename /src/
 › Press c to clear filters.

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

My package.json jest section looks like this:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "verbose": true,
    "clearMocks": true,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "globals": {
      "__DEV__": true
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/**/*.(test|spec).(tsx|ts|js)"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|jest-styled-components|styled-components)/)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

So I see the errors come from the flow typed react-native StyleSheet lib `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js`

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "artifacts",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "filesGlob": ["typings/index.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "types": ["react", "react-native", "jest"],
  "exclude": ["android", "ios", "build", "node_modules", "**/*.js"],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "lib": ["dom", "es7"]
}
```

I searched the web for any clue, played with the values of `transformIgnorePatterns` and tsconfig to no avail.

When I run the project in ios/android it compiles and works without any issues.

Here is the repo:

https://github.com/ishabo/clate